# Emscripten javascript library

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I made two examples :

- the first is a menu in 3D.
- the second is an animation in 3D also.

They are both compiled to webgl by using emscripten.
How to use these two examples to introduce them in the same canvas simply by using calls ?(creating some sort of library).

I found a solution which is an interaction between many canvas, but it's unappreciated due to the use of separated canvas, so they look that they are not in te same interface --> this is bad for the animation.